# Returning a lazy loaded entity in the JSON response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with my `Club` entity - I'm using `LAZY` fetch type and `ModelMapper` to return my JSON. The problem is that if I use `LAZY` instead of `EAGER` what I get as a response of `GET` `/api/players/{id}` is:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy
```

and a screenshot from Postman:

[image]

When I debug my controller's action:

```
@GetMapping("/api/players/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<PlayerDto> getPlayer(@PathVariable String id) {
        Player foundPlayer = playerInterface.getPlayer(Long.valueOf(id));
        PlayerDto playerToDto = convertToDto(foundPlayer);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(playerToDto);
    }

...

 private PlayerDto convertToDto(Player player) {
        return modelMapper.map(player, PlayerDto.class);
    }
```

it seems like both `foundPlayer` and `playerToDto` have the `Club` like this:

[image]

but when I do `foundPlayer.getClub().getName()` I get a proper name. I know it's probably expected behavior, but I would love to have the `Club` returned in my response like this (screenshot from the response if `EAGER` is set):
[image]

without having to set the fetch type to `EAGER`.

My `Player` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    private String firstName;


    private String lastName;;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Club club;
```

My `Club` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Club {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Player> players;
```

`getPlayer` method from the `PlayerService` (the one, that the controller calls):

```
 @Override
    public Player getPlayer(Long id) {
        Optional<Player> foundPlayer = playerRepository.findById(id);
        return foundPlayer.orElseThrow(PlayerNotFoundException::new);
    }
```

`PlayerToDto`:

```
package pl.ug.kchelstowski.ap.lab06.dto;

import pl.ug.kchelstowski.ap.lab06.domain.Club;

public class PlayerDto {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Club club;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Club getClub() {
        return club;
    }

    public void setClub(Club club) {
        this.club = club;
    }



}
```

Comment: It is still not clear what your application needs to receive when you fetch Players. If you want the club data every time included with the player, it has to be fetched ever time. You can either make the relationship eager OR create a special accessor in the repository that triggers the relationship (fetch joins within the query, a entity fetch/load graph, or access an attribute within the clubs to ensure it is fetched). There is no need for a separate DTO if you don't want the relationship - just mark it with JSON ignorable and it won't be included, so can be left lazily/unfetched.

Comment: I want to have when fetching a player/list of players (when fetching it from the controller!), but I thought that making it `EAGER` is not the best idea, since I might use not always need to use players, if I make some other operations with the players not related to the API endpoint I provided.

Comment: So I just thought about it in a way, that I only need the information of clubs eagerly when making API calls: getting all players and getting a single player. But on the other hand I thought that I might do some operations with the players (e.g. setting all of them some property at once), where I wouldn't need the information of their Clubs then. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this is the expected behavior of lazy loading. It's a good thing, don't set it to eager! Instead of returning a Club @Entity class directly on your response body, you should create a ClubDto and initialize it with another convertToDto method. It's kinda tedious (I like using [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) and [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to alleviate that), but it'll induce Hibernate to make all the queries you need.

```java
@Data
public class ClubDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@Mapper
public interface ClubMapper {
    public ClubDTO mapToDto(Club club);
}
```

---

Oops, didn't realize you were already using [ModelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/). I'm not too familiar with that, but it sounds like it will just work if you swap Club for ClubDto.

Comment: I'm trying to proceed with your suggestion, I'll get back in a moment

Comment: This has the exact same costs as what the OP posted as a solution - you are taking a full club entity and ignoring everything except the id+name properties. The player->club reference will still get triggered 'lazily' so as a separate query, and load eveything not marked lazy just for those two values.

Comment: Right, but it's better. You shouldn't manually invoke a bunch of extra queries via service methods, you should let Hibernate do its thing through the getters. With FetchType.EAGER, would it be a nice single join query? That might be appropriate for the current simple entities, but not as the structure and logic get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution guys, but I'd like to hear from you if it can be done this way, or it is some kind of anti-pattern.
I just simply set the `playerToDto`'s Club to the brandly new fetched `Club` with the ID of the `foundPlayer`

```
@GetMapping("/api/players/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<PlayerDto> getPlayer(@PathVariable String id) {
        Player foundPlayer = playerInterface.getPlayer(Long.valueOf(id));
        PlayerDto playerToDto = convertToDto(foundPlayer);
        playerToDto.setClub(clubInterface.getClub(foundPlayer.getClub().getId()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(playerToDto);
    }
```

In the end I came up with this:

```
@GetMapping("/api/players")
    ResponseEntity<List<PlayerDto>> getAllPlayers() {
        List<PlayerDto> playersList = playerInterface.getAllPlayers().stream().map(this::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
        playersList.forEach(playerInterface::fetchClubToPlayer);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(playersList);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/players/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<PlayerDto> getPlayer(@PathVariable String id) {
        Player foundPlayer = playerInterface.getPlayer(Long.valueOf(id));
        PlayerDto playerToDto = convertToDto(foundPlayer);
        playerInterface.fetchClubToPlayer(playerToDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(playerToDto);
    }
```

```
public PlayerDto fetchClubToPlayer(PlayerDto player) {
        if (player.getClub() != null) {
            Club club = clubInterface.getClub(player.getClub().getId());
            player.setClub(club);
        }
        return player;
    }
```

is it fine?

Comment: Definitely an antipattern. What would you do if it was many-to-many and there was a whole list of clubs? And each club had a bunch of its own lazily loaded child objects?

Comment: so what would you suggest, where should I do converting the club to dto in my code?

Comment: Check my answer. Basically just make a ClubDto, a Club -> ClubDto converter method, and call that inside your Player -> PlayerDto converter method.

Comment: do you say that I should do it here? but how?

`private PlayerDto convertToDto(Player player) { return modelMapper.map(player, PlayerDto.class)  }`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ModelMapper, but from what I can tell, it should just work if you change `private Club club;` to `private ClubDto club` in your PlayerDto class.

Comment: I don't know why this would be an anti pattern - seems fine to me. There are more efficient ways to fetch the club ids and the player entities in a single query without triggering the relationship, but what you have is a common approach that can easily be optimized in the future IF necessary. If you players are cached, they may already have the referenced clubs fetched - or adding caching in the future is an alternative way to have the getClub cost less.

Comment: that would change everything, because I'm struggling with creating this ClubDto and making it work with this problem especially that I can't invoke `clubInterface` and `clubMapper` to the `PlayerDto`.

Comment: @Chris could you check my edited answer? Is the current version fine?

Comment: getAllPlayers, if you want to have all clubs fetched where/when you are using it, should be changed or a special accessor created so that you fetch the players and clubs in one statement. The current approach, it'll be one query for all players, but then N queries to fetch a club for all N players returned. I may have said you can keep optimizations until later, but you might as well do that one upfront. Same with returning all players - I would strongly recommend adding pagination so that it can scale.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`@EntityGraph`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) to configure the fetch plan of the resulting method's query. For example, you can declare a method in `PlayerRepository` to find a `Player` entity by id, apart from the default `findById` method, where its `Club` entity would be fetched eagerly.

```java
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long>{
   ...
   @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"club"})
   Optional<Player> findWithClubFetchedEagerlyById(LongId);
}
```

By providing `attributePaths`, fields that should be fetched eagerly are defined.

If the `Club` entity should be always fetched eagerly when you call the `findById` method then there's no need for a separate method, therefore you can annotate the default one with `@EntityGraph`.

With this solution, the network traversal is minimized because all needed data is fetched at once from a database.

Comment: is it a similar solution that if I made `@Query("Select players from Player players left join fetch players.club)` ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. The difference is that you don't have to write a query yourself. Imagine that you have multiple associated entities that you want to fetch eagerly, join fetch would have to be written for all that entities. But if you use `@EntityGraph` you just have to list all field names in `attributePaths`.